# ASPNET Core MVC - Form to GET url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Good evening,

I have a simple question that I can't seem to find answer to anywhere.

I have a controller method with HttpGet route set like this:

```
[HttpGet("tools/browse/{table}/{row}/{offset}")]
```

My question is simple and I know that a lot of people would be interested in the answer aswell.

How does one use such form:

```
    <form action="/tools/browse/{table}/{row}/{offset}" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="table" value="" />
        <input type="number" name="row" value="" />
        <input type="number" name="offset" value="" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

..so that {table}, {row} and {offset} contain values from the form itself?

I know that the workaround would be using post or simply parsing the form data within function - but I want the url, so the user can copy it, bookmark it and so on.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will probably need to use JavaScript to construct the form action before submitting.

Comment: @Nkosi I thought so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery, this should do it (make sure you give the form an id attribute (in this case it is id=form):

```
$("#form").submit(function( e ) {
  // prevent submit
  e.preventDefault();

  // get values
  var table = $("#form input[name=table]").val();
  var row = $("#form input[name=row]").val();
  var offset = $("#form input[name=offset]").val();

  //construct url
  var url = "/tools/browse/" + table + "/" +row +"/" + offset;

  //submit form
  $("#form").attr("action", url).submit();
});
```

Check the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/teriansilva/pr2adj8m/

**Note** that it is not validating if the input fields actually have values at all.